# Hosted a Drupal 7 site, but not able to clear cache, run cron

Tags: caching, drupal, cron

I hosted my very first site a drupal 7 site(mysite.com) and what I did is-
Copied local drupal code-set of my local site(mysite_beta.com)to the server and imported the my local DB.

Now I am not able to run cron(admin>>config>>cron) also not able to clear cache(admin>>config>>performance). It is giving me blank page whenever I push these buttons also I have checked that all my local PHP extensions are enabled on server as well.

Comment: Have you looked into web server logs or tried enabling debug mode in PHP?

Comment: I have been through this problem, most probably there might be problem with your hosting server, OR else you can try installing Drush and try running cron.

Comment: I find with my hosting provider, 1and1, clearing the cache from the site runs out of memory. Instead I use drush which works fine.

Comment: It's a third party server and I dont have access to the Server, I mean shell access. So will not be able to install DRUSH. Also no access to server LOGS.

Answer (score 0):

If all PHP extensions are correct, most likely it is a memory problem. There are a number of ways you can increase the memory limit PHP can reach, the method to use, depends on the host provide and the freedom it gives you.

You can try one of these (I'd start with number 2):

1. **Using the Drupal Tweaks module**: http://drupal.org/project/drupal_tweaks
2. **Modifying the php.ini**, provided you have the access.

   - Locate the php.ini file you are currently using, you can use the phpinfo() function to find it.
   - Change the memory_limit parameter in the php.ini file. Something like:

     memory_limit = 128M ;
   - Restart Apache. Many hosts take care of this, and all you have to do is save the file.
3. **.htaccess**

Look for the .htaccess file in the Drupal root directory, then, go to section that reads:

> ## Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
>
> ## but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

right after these lines, add the following line:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

**4. settings.php**

Edit sites/default/settings.php. This will only affect the site using this file.

Search for the PHP settings section, add the following line at the end of that section:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

I hope you can use one of these methods.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for very well formatted reply.
I created a node with body to show phpinfo() values, it is showing 128M against memory_limit.
Another thing what I found is under reports it says- 'Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running', when I clicked on 'Run Cron'(admin>>config>>cron).

Comment: Try increasing the memory, higher than 128M, to rule out it's a memory problem. For example, set it to 256M and check if it's reading the change properly, then re-run cron.